# How can I now the rules of a built machine learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, knn

How can I now the rules of a built machine learning model? 
I mean when I create a machine learning (ex. KNN, SVM) using python, how can I know how the data is divided into the classes and based on what any data point is decided to belong into a class?

Comment: Given your profile, you seem to know some machine learning. I find your question surprising, are you asking how does Machine Learning algorithms work or am I missing a subtelty?

Comment: Actually, you did not understand my question. I mean How I extract the rules of ML model after creating the model using scikit-learn. @JosephBudin